# Models form with foreign key

Tags: python, django

```
class Data(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    data = models.ForeignKey(Data)
```

forms.py:

```
class DataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
```

How to add to this form photo upload?

Comment: meh, something about Inline formsets, I think. take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two possible answers:

A. Use two forms and post them to the same view. Persist the `Data` object first, then create the `Photo` object without committing it to the database, assign the data attribute to the `data` instance, and then call `.save()` on the `photo` instance (example provided below).

B. Use an inline model formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

[EDIT]

```
class Data(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    data = models.ForeignKey(Data)

class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data

class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        exclude = ('data',)

def your_view(request):
    data_form = DataForm(request.POST or None)
    photo_form = PhotoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if data_form.is_valid() and photo_form.is_valid():
            data = data_form.save()
            photo = photo_form.save(commit=False)
            photo.data = data
            photo.save()
            # do something else here, like a redirect to another view.
    return render(request, 'your-template.html',
        {'data_form': data_form, 'photo_form': photo_form})
```

Make sure your form is using: `multipart/form-data` as the enctype, or `request.FILES` will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Add manualy `ImageField` to Form and overide `save` method to create a photo :

```
class DataForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
    photo = forms.ImageField()

    def save(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        data = super(DataForm, self).save(*arg, **kwargs)
        if 'photo' in self.data :
           Photo.objects.create(
              photo=self.data['photo'],
              data=data
           )
        return data
```

Comment: ModelForm(s) should return the object they create. I've edited your answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. If I try upload photo I have error: "This field is required". Of course, the field(photo) is not empty